# android hide inner RelativeLayout prevent activity from appearing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout with inner RelativeLayouts,

I need to hide some RelativeLayouts inside of it depending on some logic,

the problem is that if I hide any of my inner RelativeLayouts, the activity doesent appear,

I have [checked this page](http://www.ceveni.com/2009/07/switching-between-layouts-in-android.html) that do what Im doing, but mine doesnt work??

here my code,

XML FOR THE ACTIVITY

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/warning_bgnd"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_warning"
    style="@style/okWarningButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="62dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_warningA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_warning"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/warning_red"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/warningTitleA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="70dip"
        android:paddingTop="0px"
        android:text="@string/textarea_warning_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/warningMessageA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/warningTitleA"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="70dip"
        android:text="@string/textarea_warning_cat_a"
        android:textColor="#B5B5B5"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>


  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_warningB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_warning"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/warning_orange"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/warningTitleB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="70dip"
        android:paddingTop="0px"
        android:text="@string/textarea_warning_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/warningMessageB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/warningTitleB"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="70dip"
        android:text="@string/textarea_warning_cat_b"
        android:textColor="#B5B5B5"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_warningC"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="275dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_warning"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/warning_green"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/warningTitleC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="70dip"
        android:paddingTop="0px"
        android:text="@string/textarea_warning_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/warningMessageC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/warningTitleC"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="70dip"
        android:text="@string/textarea_warning_cat_c"
        android:textColor="#B5B5B5"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

AND THE CODE in the java file

```
   public class WarningActivity extends PrestartAbstractActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_warning);

    //myWarningLayouts
    RelativeLayout layoutA = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.layout_warningA);
    RelativeLayout layoutB = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.layout_warningB);
    RelativeLayout layoutC = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.layout_warningC);




    //retrieve data for intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String warningType = intent.getStringExtra("type");


    Log.d("mensa", "me entro en warning ::"+warningType);


    //TODO, IMAGE BUTTON!!

    Button newPreStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_warning);
    newPreStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            restartForms();
        }
    }) ;


    //manage warning type

    int warningTypeInt = Integer.valueOf(warningType.toString());


    switch (warningTypeInt) {
    case 0:
        Log.d("mensa", "never happens");
        break;
    case 1:
        Log.d("mensa", "case 1");

        layoutA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layoutB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        layoutC.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        break;
    case 2:
        Log.d("mensa", "case 2");
        break;
    case 3:
        Log.d("mensa", "case 3");
        break;
    case 4:
        Log.d("mensa", "case 4");
        break;
    case 5:
        Log.d("mensa", "case 5");
        break;
    case 6:
        Log.d("mensa", "case 6");
        break;
    case 7:
        Log.d("mensa", "case 7");

        break;
    default:
    Log.d("mensa", "default switch");
    }

}
```

SO , in my test, if I have case 1, 
never gets called, cannot even see the inner logs of the activity?

what is missing to hide my inner layouts?

Thanks!

Comment: in your xml at the bottom there should be two closing tags for relative layout. Was that left by mistake in the post or is it the exact replica of your code ?

Comment: For Me the above xml and code is working well as you are expecting it to work... if I give 1 instead of warningTypeInt inside Switch case only first relative Layout is Visible. The Problem is with warningTypeInt check what value it is retrieving..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined the layout_width and layout_height for the button. Check logcat it should be giving some kind of error. This code works when you provide width and height to the button and provide some text or image to be displayed on button. You can do that by

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/warningBtnText"
```

Comment: hi thanks I have fixed this, but that unfortunately doesn't fix my problem, what can it be?

Comment: can you post the log cat output ? Another thing is while creating warningTypeInt you may get a exception. Check the value of warningType using log before parsing it.